# Parse XML for a column value in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, xml, join

I've set up a SQL fiddle to mimic the tables that I currently have which can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7675e/5

I have 2 tables that I would like to join (Things and ThingData) which is easy enough, but I would like 1 of the columns to be coming from a value that is pulled from parsed XML in one of the columns in ThingData.

Ideally the output would look something like this:

```
thingID | thingValue | xmlValue
1       | aaa        | a
```

As you can see in the fiddle, I'm able to parse a single XML string at a time, but I'm unsure of how to go from here to using the parsing stuff as a column in a join.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your SQL Fiddle to demonstrate; the number one issue you're facing is that you're not using an XML type for your XML column.  That's going to cause headaches down the road as people shove crap in that column :P

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c674/2

Comment: Thanks, I agree about the column type but unfortunately that's not up to me.  I just came up with a different solution (after finally finding a more relevant question on here) and it looks just like Hano's below.  I initially thought the answer would need CROSS APPLY like you are using but what Hano and I have doesn't do that.  Are you able to explain the differences between our solutions just for my own edification?

Comment: The big difference is that CROSS APPLY allows you to retrieve multiple nodes from the XML (e.g., you want to pull two values of c1 for each row); if you can guarantee that you'll only ever want to pull 1 node at a time, Hano's suggestion is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a change to your query that gets executed .

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = (select thingDataXML from ThingData where thingDataID = 3)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.testing.org/a/b/c/d123')
SELECT
    t.[thingID]
  , t.[thingValue]
  , CONVERT(XML,td.[thingDataXML]).value('(/anItem/a1/b1/c1/text())[1]','Varchar(1)') as xmlValue 
FROM Things t
    join ThingData td
        on td.[thingDataID] = t.[thingDataID]
```

This should join from you main table into the table containing the xml and would then retreive the one value in the xml for you, note that if you would like to return multiple values for the one row you will need to either concatinate the answer or perhaps decide on a crossjoin to then use the data with the other data set to perform some logic with.

EDIT:

The answer for your question would be that both have a use case, the cross join he showed above creates an accesible table to query which uses a tiny bit more memory while the query runs but can be accessed many times, where as the normal xquery value function just reads a node which would only work to read a single value from the xml.

Cross join would be the solution if you would like to construct tabular data out of your xml.

Comment: Thanks, like I mentioned to Stuart above, came up with a solution exactly like yours, now I'm curious as to which is better, and why.